# Can I put $x = \dfrac{π}{2}$ in $ \tan{2x} = \dfrac{2\tan{x}}{1 - \tan^2{x}} $?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

In the textbook it is written about the equation that $ 2x \neq n \pi + \dfrac{\pi}{2} $.

Does that mean x can be equal to $ n \pi + \dfrac{\pi}{2} $ ?

Comment: $\tan (n\pi + \frac {\pi} 2)$ is not defined, so you cannot put $x=n\pi+\frac {\pi} 2$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy In the textbook, the only thing mentioned about the domain is that $2x \neq n \pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$. Can you tell me why it is not written that $ x \neq n \pi + \frac{\pi}{2} $ as well ?

Comment: It must be  a typo. I don't see any problem with $2x=\pi +\frac {\pi} 2$, for example.

Comment: @arandomguy, because that's not cos(2x) is 0 at 2x=π/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, $\tan x$ is undefined  at $ x = n \pi + \frac{\pi}{2} $. Similarly $\tan 2x$ is undefined  at $ 2x =n \pi + \frac{\pi}{2} $

Therefore for defining $\tan x$ & $\tan 2x$
$$x\ne n \pi + \frac{\pi}{2}, \ \ \ \  \ \ 2x\ne n \pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Your answer is a bit wrong

Comment: let me know that

Comment: 2x **=** π/2, it is valid. But That formula is not defined for 2x=π/2.

Comment: no, $\tan 2x$ is undefined at $2x=\pi/2$ so why is it valid?

Comment: Oh wait, you're right.

Comment: Could you edit the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Actually $x,2x$ both should be $\not\equiv\dfrac\pi2\pmod{\pi}$ to keep $\tan x,\tan2x$ defined

But we can take limit  and set $\tan x=\dfrac1t$ to find

$$L=\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi2}\dfrac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}=\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{\dfrac2t}{1-\dfrac1{t^2}}=\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{2t}{t^2-1}\text{ as }t\ne0\text{ as }t\to0$$

$$\implies L= 0$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x=\frac{\pi}{2}\pm\epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0$, $\tan x\sim\mp\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, so $\tan\frac{\pi}{2}$ is undefined. (It's not even $\infty$, because it approaches $\mp\infty$ depending on the direction.) But now$$\tan2x\sim\frac{\mp2/\epsilon}{-O(1/\epsilon^2)}\sim\pm2\epsilon,$$which has $\epsilon\to0$ limit $0$. This agrees with $\tan\pi=0$, of course.